# What is this icon on the task bar?

Tags: windows-vista, taskbar, icons

I'm talking about the 3rd icon from the left, that looks sort of like an envelope.  It's curious, because I often get several of these, but they mysteriously "evaporate" when you mouse over them, so it's impossible to "ask" them what they are.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a "New mail" icon shown by Thunderbird that crashed.

(If a program crashes, Explorer's notification area doesn't notice that until it needs to send an event like mouse move to the program, at which point it removes the dead icon.)

Comment: Except that Thunderbird has not crashed (that I know of).  It's generally not (visibly) running when these appear, nor had I left it running.  (When I check just now with Process Explorer I see that Thunderbird is running in background, though.  I guess it must start on a timer and then later kill itself or some such.)